# Can't return the a SQL select count on PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

So I have this code to count the number of 'Guides' by counting the number of IDs on the table.

```
    function getGuideCount() {
  global $db;
  $query = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS count FROM kk_hq_guides ");
  $fetch = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  return $fetch;
}
```

I am returning the value to a vardump and I am getting this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["count"]=> string(2) "36" } } Array
```

This is correct, I have an array with the key 'Count' storing the amount of guides.

Problem comes when I try to print that value.

```
$guideCount=getGuideCount();    
print($guideCount['count']);
```

results in the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: count in ... on line 130. (Line 130 is this:  return $fetch;  )
```

Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, globals are truly awful. Instead, pass dependencies in where required.

Second, your query will only ever return one row with one column so `fetchAll` is superfluous.

Try this instead...

```
function getGuideCount(PDO $db) {
    $query = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM kk_hq_guides ");
    return $query->fetchColumn();
}
```

then...

```
$guideCount = getGuideCount($db);
echo $guideCount;
```

Comment: I will stick to my global $db; method since I include my database file in the php file where I store my sql query functions. I am not doing OOP on this one so that's why. I do like your approach with fetchColumn(); since this returns a string with the value which is perfect. No need to fiddle with arrays. Thanks!

Comment: Dependency injection has **nothing** to do with OOP. Relying on global state is only going to cause issues later on.

Comment: I have to include the database on the file that will send the $db paramenter to the query function, how could this be better than having the database included directly to the file with my queries?

Comment: @AlexKvazos Where you include the database file is irrelevant as long as the `$db` variable is in scope where it is required. Your functions don't need to know anything about the database other than the fact that they will be given a PDO object to work with.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks for this tip. I will use it in my future projects.

Answer (score 2):

`$guideCount[0]['count']`

The first item in the `$guideCount` array is an array containing one element with a key of 'count'.

Comment: Note to OP: The "array-within-an-array" structure you see here is produced by `fetchAll()`; think of it as "row-within-result" where the result array contains 0 or more rows, and each row array contains 0 or more columns with a value or `NULL`. If you know that you are only going to have at most one row (as with this simple `COUNT()` query), you can use `fetch()` instead to get only the one row. If you use `fetch()` here, you will be able to access the value by `$guideCount['count']`.

Comment: I did it with just fetch(); instead of fetchAll(); and I got the same result: 
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["count"]=> string(2) "36" } }

EDIT: It did work, I didnt FTP up.